# Performance comparison between CTE and CTE with fewer columns with inner join

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have the following queries. I am not sure about why is the one using inner join takes less time to execute, shouldn't it take more time than the first one?

Query #1:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPORAL 
(
     ID INT, 
     NAME NVARCHAR(300), 
     LASTNAME NVARCHAR(100),
     PARENTID INT,
     [LEVEL] INT
)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, PARENTID, 0 [LEVEL], FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
    FROM 
        PERSON
    WHERE 
        ID = 1123643

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   
        P.ID, P.PARENTID, C.[LEVEL] + 1, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME
    FROM 
        PERSON P 
    INNER JOIN 
        CTE C ON C.ID = P.PARENTID
)
INSERT INTO #TEMPORAL (ID, NAME, LASTNAME, PARENTID, [LEVEL])
    (SELECT 
         ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, [LEVEL]
     FROM 
         CTE)

SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME, PARENTID, [LEVEL]
FROM #TEMPORAL
```

Query #2:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPORAL 
(
     ID INT, 
     NAME NVARCHAR(300), 
     LASTNAME NVARCHAR(100),
     PARENTID INT,
     [LEVEL] INT
)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, PARENTID, 0 [LEVEL]
    FROM 
        PERSON
    WHERE 
        ID = 1123643

    UNION ALL

    SELECT   
        P.ID, P.PARENTID, C.[LEVEL] + 1
    FROM 
        PERSON P 
    INNER JOIN 
        CTE C ON C.ID = P.PARENTID
)
INSERT INTO #TEMPORAL (ID, PARENTID, [LEVEL])
    (SELECT ID, PARENTID, [LEVEL]
     FROM CTE)

SELECT 
    ID, PARENTID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME
FROM 
    #TEMPORAL T 
INNER JOIN 
    PERSON P ON T.ID = P.ID
```

So, I am very confused about the reason of why is this happening. Can you give me some explanation? Also, if there is a better option to accomplish what I want would be great to know .

Comment: Query 2 is performing the JOIN against PERSON twice - once in the CTE construction and again in the final SELECT, while Query 1 performs that join only once. WHat leads you to think that Query 2 is doing less work?

Comment: Without seeing statistics IO and time or the very least a execution plan - I'd guess it's because of less usage of temp db

Comment: What indexes do you have on `person`? What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: I just compared executing times. The one with inner joins takes 1 less second to load the information. Does using more columns within the insert (which use a temporal table) could be the reason it is taking more time?

Comment: I have no indexes yet. Using the would make the first one faster than the second?